# zip/Postcode Digit valdiation check

Tags: php, regex, joomla, virtuemart

I need to set the postcode field to be validated to have at least one number in it but seems like im missing something becuase it is not working:

```
 if( isset( $required_fields['zip'] )) {
         echo '
         if( =(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])+$/.test(form.zip.value))) {
            alert( \'Please enter a valid Zip Code\');
            return false;
         }';

      }
```

can someone tell me what is wrong please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's that `=(` in front of your regular expression? And also: Please describe more precisely what is wrong. Have you tested your regex with a regex testing tool (like The Regex Coach) against different strings?

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response what i need exactly is that the field will not be accepted as valid if it contains no digit (the position of the digit and letters should have no effect). hope this is more clear and can help me update the code accordingly. im not a php expert so i tried to set a code from what i found on the internet. I know it is not working becuase im trying it on the live site. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you need is this:
`^(?=.*[0-9])([\w]+)$`

You were using positive look-ahead on [a-zA-Z] instead of actual character matching, and the look-aheads match only a position, not characters. Of course, the pattern [\w] can be replaced with some more restrictive pattern.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response

what i need exactly is that the field will not be accepted as valid if it contains no digit (the position of the digit and letters should have no effect).

hopethis is more clear and can help me update the code accordingly. im not a php expert so i tried to set a code from what i found on the internet

thanks

Comment: Yes, the regex I wrote matches exactly that. Have you tried it?

Comment: ok managed to make it work i used a code for US zip code and updated the area you suggested. Thank you